# Spring Boot - Spring security @ComponentScan or @Import

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have this security class

```
com.tdk.config

/**
 * @author  nunito
 * @version 1.0
 * @since  4 mar. 2017
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/tdk/config/app-${APP-KEY}.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected String loginPage = "/tdk/login";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage(getLoginPage() )
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/mockup/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/welcome/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html");


    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(new StandardPasswordEncoder())
                .withUser("nunito").password("08c461ad70fce6c74e12745931085508ccb2090f2eae3707f6b62089c634ddd2636f380f40109dfb").roles("ADMIN").and()
                .withUser("nunito").password("4cfbf05e4493d17125c547fdba494033d7aceee9310f253f3e96c4f928333d2436d669d63a84fe4f").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    public String getLoginPage() {
        return loginPage;
    }

    public void setLoginPage(String loginPage) {
        this.loginPage = loginPage;
    }
```

Using this config file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.tdk.config")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TdkCloudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TdkCloudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have a 404 wherever I access in the URL

But this config everything is OK

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class TdkCloudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TdkCloudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I would like to know the difference, because for me is two different ways to do exactly the same think

Comment: Can you try removing '@EnableWebSecurity' as it disable spring-boot auto configuration also no need for '@ComponentScan' as spring boot do scan all sub package , same for '@EnableAutoConfiguration' not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an explanation of [`@Import`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) and [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), this is not an answer to your question (because I don't know why it doesn't work with ComponentScan), more like a hint for it.

[`@Import`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) is used for importing other configurations, so if a class is annotated with `@Configuration` and there are some beans defined there, they will be imported to the application context, e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class config{
    @Bean
    public ClassA a(){
        return new ClassA();
    }
}

@Import({config.Class}) // import Bean for ClassA
```

[`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) scans all classes annotated with `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository` and have a one to one bean mapped to each class.
e.g.

```
@Component
public class ClassB {}

@ComponentScan // import Bean ClassB
```

After the version 4.2 of Spring, [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) can also scan `@Configuration` as a component. So in your case, the SecurityConfig should also be imported into the context as a component but not as a configuration.

The only thing I don't quite understand is how the [`@Import`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) triggers the execution of the code in the SecurityConfig, please give a comment if anyone knows about it.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` is also a `@Configuration` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) so that is probably why `@Import` works.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. But it might help someone.
The package of "TdkCloudApplication" is not present in the question. I'm assuming, its in a different package than "com.tdk.config".
if this is the case, then in the @ComponentScan() annotation, you have to give the package of the TdkCloudApplication and the package of "SecurityConfig"

like this.
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.tdk.config", "packageName of TdkCloudApplication"}).

Its because of @SpringBootApplication. by default it will scan for beans in that package and its subpackages. but if we annotate the class with @ComponentScan, then we have to give all the packages that we need, so that spring will check in all those areas.

Comment: Please add [`codeboxes`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) around your code ^^